# How to write an admin theme plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to change admin theme in wordpress. I have created a simple admin theme plugin (including CSS and js files) to change some simple CSS, however, there are some layout page need to be totally changed. I am wondering if anyone can help me to find an easy to change the whole layout  theme without changing source code. Is it possible to overwrite the layout in the admin theme plugin? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Instead of creation plugin , you should go with the custom theme options

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look the theme options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create "Theme Option Page" instead of creating plugin for Theme setting like colors and other style in wordpress ! For reference :
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages
It will be best option as per my experience in wordpress !

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Comment: If you like my suggestion please accept my answer, Thanks